# What's wrong with Scala Regex in case match?

Tags: regex, scala

I have two regexes `doubleRegex` and `intRegex` defined below:

```
scala> val doubleRegex = """^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$""".r
doubleRegex: scala.util.matching.Regex = ^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$

scala> val intRegex = """^[-+]?[0-9]*$""".r
intRegex: scala.util.matching.Regex = ^[-+]?[0-9]*$
```

Now I want to match a bunch of strings to detect their types:

```
scala> List(".01", "11", "1.34").map{ s => 
       s match {
          case intRegex() => "INT"
          case doubleRegex() => "DOUBLE"
          case _ => "NONE"
       }
     }
res5: List[String] = List(NONE, INT, NONE)
```

Why does it not print `List(DOUBLE, INT, DOUBLE)` ?

Comment: Use `case intRegex(_*) => "INT"` and `case doubleRegex(_*) => "DOUBLE"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a capturing group specified in the `doubleRegex`, and when executing, you get the capturing groups extracted (and the first capturing group is empty with your examples).

Use `doubleRegex(_*)` to just check if a string matches without extracting capturing groups:

```
val doubleRegex = """^[-+]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$""".r
val intRegex = """^[-+]?[0-9]*$""".r
print(List(".01", "11", "1.34").map{ s => 
   s match {
      case intRegex(_*) => "INT"
      case doubleRegex(_*) => "DOUBLE"
      case _ => "NONE"
   }
})
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/k4pH98)

Another solution is to change the capturing group into a non-capturing one:

```
val doubleRegex = """^[-+]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$""".r
                                            ^^
```

Then, you can use your `case intRegex() => "INT"`, and `case doubleRegex() => "DOUBLE"`.

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Os6EQG)

Comment: wow, the non-capturing group works. didn't know about it. thanks!